# Why java thread is not killed after processing

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I have the following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    test1();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            System.out.println("1 " + java.lang.Thread.activeCount());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("3 " + java.lang.Thread.activeCount());
    } 

    private static void test1() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("2");
    }
```

It produces the following output:

```
1 3
2
3 3
```

Why doesn't the thread finish after its done and I have another thread hanging around? and why is it different from the following:

```
Thread thread1=new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            test1();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
thread1.start();
```

that produces:

```
1 3
2
3 2
```

Comment: ThreadPools. The idea behind them is simple: creating a new thread is expensive, so let's reuse them.

Comment: So how can I control the threadpool?

Comment: The first line of your output seems to be incorrect. It should be `1  2`

Comment: @hossein what do you want to do? At least read the docs on Executors and ThreadPooling in Java

Answer (score 1):

As you can in documentation runAsync uses threadpoool https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-

The idea of pool is that one thread completes multiple tasks to avoid creating many threads. So when it completes it just waits for new task, if you runAsync something new the same thread will probably do it.